# Facebook messenger: initiate conversation from bot to user on bot framework using node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, azure, botframework

I am trying to create a chatbot whereby when user revisit the chat on facebook messenger, it will detect and initiate conversation.

Could someone please advise me?

**My current code**:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                bot.beginDialog(message.address, 'revisitDialog');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Expected result**:

```
Bot to User: Ans A

User to bot: What is b?

Bot to User: Ans B

After an hour, when the user revisit the chat....

Bot to user: hi, is there anything I can help you with?
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the functionality does not exist for what you are seeking. Bots can recognize when a user is new to a conversation and, subsequently, post a welcome message. But, there is no way for a bot to recognize a user has left their device and returned at a later point without some level of user interaction with the bot.

Steve.